# Colour Formatting

Tags: excel

Ok I need help on excel... I have an area BM46 to BM59 on worksheet 2 which i would like to change colour ( red,amber or green) dependant on the value of H43 on the same worksheet. So basically when the number is equal to 100% I want to colour it green and if it is between 90% and 99% then I want to colour it amber and if it is below 90% i want to colour it red.
Well I can do this but when it is formulated the writing that is in H43 is displayed but I want to put different text in the cells and only have the colour change... I am sure it is simple to do but i am not sure how.

Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply value-dependent formatting by selecting the cells you want and then going to

Format > Conditional formatting...

and setting the rules there.

Comment: Or Home->Styles->Conditional Formating->Color Scales/>More Rules in Excel 2007

Comment: Thank you for your reply...I am not sure if that answers my question as i can format the cell to change colour by utilising "use in formula" key in formulas... the problem I have is that it shows the value figure in text but I want other text in the box and I just want the box colour to change. I hope you understand what I am saying.

Answer (score 0):

Further to Aqua's response...

1. Use conditional formatting
2. You will need to set up multiple rules using "Use a formula to determine which cells to format".
3. Set each rule with a formula to correspond with the appropriate formatting.  If the default color was red, you only need 2 rules.  Conditional Formatting formulas need to evaluate to a True/False value.  Your formulas should look like "=IF($H$43>.99,true)" for the green, "=IF($H$43>=.9,true)" for amber.
4. Use "Conditional Formatting Rules Manager" (Alt + H + L + R shortcut) to make sure the rules are in the correct order.  Set the green rule to be first and make sure to check "Stop If True".

Your conditionally-formatted cells can have any text you want, it's only the accompanying rule formulas that need to reference H43.

Hope that helps...